# Accessing class members in after advice for execution pointcut

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I am trying to get the value of the read String after the execution of readObject() in the sample code below from an after advice which advises the readObject() join point.

```
public class Eg {

    private ObjectOutputStream output;
    private ObjectInputStream input;
    Public String request="";

    public Eg(File source){
            output; // output stream to client
            input= new ObjectInputStream( file ); 
        }

    public void method() {
            try{            
                while(true) {
                    request =(String) input.readObject();
                    //do something with request
                }//while
            }
            catch (IOException ex) 
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }

}
```

and my aspect:

```
public aspect ReadStringGetter {
    public pointcut readOperation() :
      execution(* java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject());

    after() : readOperation() {
        Eg eg = (Eg) thisJoinPoint.getThis();
        System.out.println(eg.request);
    }
}
```

Comment: public aspect ReadStringGetter 
{
    public pointcut readOperation()
        : execution(* java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject()) ;
 
    after() : readOperation() 
    {
        Eg eg =(Eg) thisJoinPoint.getThis();
     System.out.println(eg.request);  
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You could use `this` pointcut to obtain a context of join point (instance of `Eg`):

```
class Eg {
    public String request = "";
    public void method() {
        request = "xy";
        System.out.println(request);
    }
}
```

caller:

```
Eg c = new Eg();
c.method();
```

aspect:

```
public aspect MyAspect {

    pointcut EgMethodsExecution(Eg eg) : 
        execution(* Eg.method(..)) && this(eg);

    after(Eg eg) : EgMethodsExecution(eg) {
        System.out.println("~ in aspect ~ " + eg.request);
    }

}
```

output:

> xy
>   ~ in aspect ~ xy